# UV Filter that best suits Nikon 18-140 mm lens

Tags: nikon, nikon-d7000

Please let me know the size of UV filter that best suits Nikon 18-140 mm lens.

Comment: I voted this question down as it shows literally no research effort _whatsoever_. With a quick google of "Nikon 18-140 filter size" the answer can be found in the first search result without even opening up the link or leaving Google.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows that the author didn't make any effort to find an answer before posting.

Answer (score 1):

The filter thread is 67mm on the Nikon 18-140mm f/3.5-5.6G ED VR AF-S DX NIKKOR Zoom Lens.

This information can be found on the Nikon product page here: http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/lens/zoom/normalzoom/af-s_dx_18-140mmf_35-56g_ed_vr/